QGIS 3.28.11 add attribute table in Atlas
In QGIS 3.28, I created a project,it has 20 polygons in a .shp. Each polygon has a unique value with the header "code" in the attribute table. I extracted vertices and collect geometries and I also created a point layer which contains all row number, X, Y, values of all vertices of those polygons.
So the point layer has attribute values like this "code", "id", "xcoord" "ycoord". Now in the layout I want to create an Atlas, which will have the map of the each polygon and its unique coordinates.
I created my basic map skeleton. If I had to work with 2-3 polygons, I could create 2-3 layouts, and in the attribute table options, I could filter the coordinates with the "code" value and each map would have its own coordinates. But if I try to put the same filter in the atlas, it gives me an empty attribute table.
Do you know any expression that will help me to do that filtering in the Atlas map generator, so for each polygon to have its own XY table?

There is the option Filter with in the Attribute Table main properties (in the Feature Filtering section) which you can use.

The expression can then be:
"code" = attribute(@atlas_feature, 'code')

Examples:


